# How to prevent the win32 jagged-edges?

Tags: winapi

I'm creating a round button, `win32` has the `HRGN` object to define the region of window.
So here is what I do:

```
int Button_Test(HWND hwnd)
{
    //button
    HWND btn=CreateWindowEx(NULL,WC_BUTTON,"Test",(WS_TABSTOP|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_OWNERDRAW|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS),
                           10,10,80,80,hwnd,(HMENU)ID_BTN01,
                           (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),NULL);
    
    //set region.
    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(btn,&rc);
    HRGN rgn=CreateEllipticRgn(0,0,rc.right-rc.left,rc.bottom-rc.top);
    if(rgn==NULL) MessageBox(hwnd,"Create region failed.","Sorry...",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    else SetWindowRgn(btn,rgn,FALSE);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The button has the jagged-edges like this.[image]

So how to prevent the jagged-edges effect? I mean how to make the edge more smoothly , without saw edges.

using gdiplus smoothly-mode pixels combine regions, it looks like this, as far as I see , it works:
[image]

Comment: My want to use GDI+ instead of GDI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-antialiasing-with-lines-and-curves-about

Comment: gdiplus doing something with graphics, anything with window regions ?

Comment: Regions create a binary partitioning of space. A point is either inside the region, or outside. A point cannot be partway inside and outside. You cannot go beyond the physical resolution of the display device. As long as your process is DPI-aware, what you have is the best you can get.

Comment: An idea: using gdiplus draw smooth round bitmap ,according bitmap, pixel by pixel , combine the selected pixels, create the regions with pixels selected, then set the regions.

Comment: A region doesn't support sub-pixel precision. Whatever you hope to gain from using GDI+ isn't going to be reflected in the final region. Regions are all or nothing, either inside or outside. There is no *"smoothing"* mode for regions.

Comment: Im not sure why you concerned about the ```pixel belong to specific region``` , I just want to solve the saw-edges performance of window regions. I will put the picture follow my ideas. As I see, it works.